# HazelcastSerializationException with Kryo using Scala

Tags: scala, serialization, hazelcast, kryo

I am using kryo for serialization with Scala 2.11.1 and Hzaelcast 3.5 
i am trying to put my data in hazelcast map but i am getting KryoException

here is my model class

```
  @SerialVersionUID(1)
        case class User( id : Int ,name : String, userType : UserType /*UserType is Enum (EMPLOYED , UNEMPLOYED)*/ , userhistory : UserHistory) extends  Serializable{

def this()= {
this(0,"",Active, null)
}
}
```

here is `UserHistory` class

```
    @SerialVersionUID(1)
case  class UserHistory( date : DateTime = DateTime.now(), artworkStatus : ArtworkStatus = ACTIVE) extends  Serializable{

def this()={
    this(DateTime.parse("0"),ACTIVE) 
  }
}
```

here is my serializer for User class

```
class UserSerializer extends StreamSerializer[User] {


   val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)

   override def destroy() {

  }

  override def getTypeId() : Int ={
    val value : Int = 1;
    value

  }

  // takes the bytes and converts into User Object
   @throws(classOf[IOException])
  override def read(in : ObjectDataInput) : User =  {

     val kryo = new Kryo 
     val input = new Input(in.asInstanceOf[InputStream])
      log.info("********** Reading the bytes and converting into User object")
     kryo.readClassAndObject(input).asInstanceOf[User]



  }

   // takes User Object and converts into bytes
  @throws(classOf[IOException])
  override def write(out : ObjectDataOutput, obj : User) {

    val kryo= new Kryo
    val bops = new ByteArrayOutputStream
    val output = new Output(bops)
    kryo.writeClassAndObject(output , obj)
    output.flush
    output.close

    bops.writeTo(out.asInstanceOf[OutputStream])

    log.info("********** User object writen into bytes successfully")


  }


}
```

now when I put User class object from Hcast client into the respective map like this

```
map.set(user.id , user)
```

it gives me these exception:

```
 Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class cannot be created (non-static member class): scala.Enumeration$Val
```

Complete `StackTraces` from `Hcast Client` :

> 7:52:25.094 152121 [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2]
>   UserSerializer INFO - ********** User object writen into bytes
>   successfully 17:52:29.667 156694
>   [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] play ERROR - Cannot invoke the
>   action, eventually got an error:
>   com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException:
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class cannot be created
>   (non-static member class): scala.Enumeration$Val Serialization trace:
>   userType (UserHistory)
>   UserHistory (User) 17:52:29.832
>   156859 [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] application ERROR -
>
> ! @6nb1hbglj - Internal server error, for (POST)
>   [/user/signup] ->
>
> play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution
>   exception[[HazelcastSerializationException:
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class cannot be created
>   (non-static member class): scala.Enumeration$Val Serialization trace:
>   userType (UserHistory)
>   UserHistory (User)    at
>   play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296)
>   ~[play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]  at
>   play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402)
>   [play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]   at
>   play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320)
>   [play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]   at
>   play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320)
>   [play_2.11-2.3.8.jar:2.3.8]

following are the `StackTraces` from `Hcast Server`

> > 17:52:28.010 [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.partition-operation.thread-0] INFO  models.serializers.UserSerializer - ********** Reading the bytes
> >     and converts into User object 17:52:28.990
> >     [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.partition-operation.thread-0] ERROR
> >     c.h.map.impl.operation.SetOperation - [192.168.15.20]:5701 [dev] [3.5]
> >     com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class cannot be created
> >     (non-static member class): scala.Enumeration$Val Serialization trace:
> >     userType (UserHistory) UserHistory (User)
> >     com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException:
> >     com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class cannot be created
> >     (non-static member class): scala.Enumeration$Val Serialization trace:
> >     userType (UserHistory) UserHistory (User)     at
> >     com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.handleException(SerializationServiceImpl.java:380)
> >     ~[hazelcast-3.5.jar:3.5]  at
> >     com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:282)
> >     ~[hazelcast-3.5.jar:3.5]  at
> >     com.hazelcast.map.impl.mapstore.AbstractMapDataStore.toObject(AbstractMapDataStore.java:78)
> >     ~[hazelcast-3.5.jar:3.5]  at
> >     com.hazelcast.map.impl.mapstore.writethrough.WriteThroughStore.add(WriteThroughStore.java:39)
> >     ~[hazelcast-3.5.jar:3.5]  at
> >     com.hazelcast.map.impl.mapstore.writethrough.WriteThroughStore.add(WriteThroughStore.java:31)
> >     ~[hazelcast-3.5.jar:3.5]  at
> >     com.hazelcast.map.impl.DefaultRecordStore.set(DefaultRecordStore.java:803)
> >     ~[hazelcast-3.5.jar:3.5]  at
> >     com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.SetOperation.run(SetOperation.java:41)
> >     ~[hazelcast-3.5.jar:3.5]  at
> >     com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:137)
> >     ~[hazelcast-3.5.jar:3.5]  at
> >     com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.processOperation(OperationThread.java:154)
> >     [hazelcast-3.5.jar:3.5]   at
> >     com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:110)
> >     [hazelcast-3.5.jar:3.5]   at
> >     com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.doRun(OperationThread.java:101)
> >     [hazelcast-3.5.jar:3.5]   at
> >     com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:76)
> >     [hazelcast-3.5.jar:3.5] Caused by:
> >     com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class cannot be created
> >     (non-static member class): scala.Enumeration$Val

Please Help me!!

Answer (score 1):

Usually with Scala, you should use the `StdInstantiatorStrategy`, e.g.

```
val kryo = new Kryo
val is = new org.objenesis.strategy.StdInstantiatorStrategy
kryo.setInstantiatorStrategy(instantiatorStrategy)
```

Not sure if that will fix your issue, but I haven't seen any such problems.

Comment: Works perfectly for Java too

Answer (score 0):

Did you register enum serializer as mentioned on [github](https://github.com/romix/akka-kryo-serialization) ?

```
        // Serialization of Scala enumerations
        kryo.addDefaultSerializer(classOf[scala.Enumeration#Value], classOf[EnumerationSerializer])
        kryo.register(Class.forName("scala.Enumeration$Val"))
        kryo.register(classOf[scala.Enumeration#Value])
```

Exception is pretty clear that it can not create `userType` which is enum.

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class cannot be created (non-static member class): scala.Enumeration$Val Serialization trace: userType (UserHistory) UserHistory (User)
```

Comment: should i write serializer separatly for my enum (EnumerationSerializer in your solution)?

Comment: I'm not expert at kryo library but default Enum serializer should be ok for your custom UserType enum just explicitly register it like in the answer.